# Plotting time vs time on MS excel 2016

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010, bar-chart

I am trying to plot time taken over a period of day from 12:00:00 Am to 11:00:00 PM  vs time taken by a process to run during this period in MS excel 2016 .

```
  Refresh Time  Time Taken
  12:04:38 AM    00:02:03.420 
  12:17:50 AM    00:03:11.206 
  12:31:04 AM    00:02:14.365 
  12:44:16 AM    00:03:11.734 
  12:44:16 AM    00:03:20.000
```

I would love to plot a chart bar/ scattered/ line  chart anything which would help me understand difference in the time taken .Guide me with the ideas .If it is not possible to be done by excel , suggest a good chart in any programming language which i can explore . I used pivot and scattered chart , I was able to bring up the time on the x axis but not plot it against the time taken by the process

Answer (score 1):

You could plot the time taken values in a horizontal bar chart, with the refresh time as the categories on the vertical axis.

Format the vertical axis to plot categories in reverse order, so the earliest plot time is at the top.

Format the horizontal axis with a major unit of `0.000694444444444444` (which is one minute) and reduce the gap width.

[image]

Or you can build an XY scatter chart with the refresh time on the horizontal axis and the time taken on the vertical axis.

[image]

In the screenshot above, the horizontal axis is set at a major unit of ten minutes (0.006944444), but if you want to plot a whole day, you may want to use bigger units.

**Tip**: before you select the data, delete the text "Refresh Time" above the column of time stamps. If there is no text in that cell, Excel will place the time stamps on the category axis. (If there is text in the cell, Excel will try to plot the time stamps as a data series. ) After the chart has been created, you can type the text back into the cell.

Comment: Thanks a ton !is it possible to add a line on the points of XY scatter chart .

Comment: I’m not able to bring up the horizontal bar chart , I could see time on the vertical axis , but not able to bring up Time taken all I’m seeing is a blacked out chart . How to reduce the gap width . Which width I should be trying to drink down

Comment: Yes, the XY Scatter chart series can be formatted to have a line. It's in the formatting options for the series. If you have a lot of data points, then the horizontal bar chart may not be the best option, because things will overlap unless you make the chart very, very tall.